# IOS Constraints for height (dynamic height change)

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, xib, nib

I am having trouble allowing my XIB file to contain constraint values for a view that will increase the view without covering the view beneath it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

essentially

```
(view1 here) -- lets say
(view2 here) -- lets say
```

both are in a larger view but when view 1 increases like so

```
(view1 here)
(view1 increased content here) -- view2 would now be covered instead of

(view1 here)
(view1 increased content here)
(view2 here) -- like it should be.
```

Sorry for not using pictures, but the question seemed really simple. I tried adding constraints but that hasn't worked is there something that is easier to do programmatically, or? I have been spending so much time on this, and I know I could do a couple things, but I don't understand why my constraints don't work when I have vertical spacing and top of view etc. nothing seems to work.

[image]

EDIT UPDATE:
As you can see from the picture I need those all to size accordingly. When I change the tableview height of one of them, along with label correspondence to where they are. The imageview will always be there, they are all contained in a view that is in a scrollview as shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a constraint between the Top of View2 and the Bottom of View 1 Equal to 0.